# How can I sort Views output by whether or not field content matches a string?

Tags: views

I feel like there must be a module for this, but I can't find one.

What I have is a field with 4 possible values. I want to sort items with a specific one of the values to the top, then everything else in order by creation date.

In SQL, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT fields FROM table ORDER BY textfield = "text" DESC, datefield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two different approaches here:

Add a single view with multiple sort criteria:
[image: Views Sort Criteria Example]

Create two views:

- The first view should include a filter criteria with operator "is one of" for the textfield value you want to use (ex. "text") and a sort criteria based on date.
- The second view should include a filter criteria for "is none of" for the textfield value used in the first view (ex. text).
- Within the second view, add a field "Global: View area" within the view header selecting the first view created.

The second option requires additional configuration, but should give you more control over the sorting of the different groups. In addition, using multiple sort criteria for text fields occasionally causes duplicates to appear and the multi-view approach avoids this problem.

**Update**

Check out [Views Argument Extras](https://drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras). This module provides a method to sort based on argument criteria (such as arbitrary fields) without using weights. Here's my configuration:
[image: Views Argument Extras Configuration]

The above configuration will be too simplified for your 'sort by day, then text field, then time configuration', but it's a good start. To sort by day, then text field, then time you'll need to use the date module and limit the elements that it sorts by (checkboxes).

If this is something you plan to apply globally, consider adding the [Weight](https://drupal.org/project/weight) module and sort based on that instead of Views Argument Extras.

Comment: I like that, and it works for my example above. Of course, this answer proves I oversimplified my question...what I'd really like to do is sort by DAY of post, then by whether this text matches, then by HOUR of post - so posts with this type filter to the top of each day, then there's everything else for that day, then for the next day this type filters to the top again.

Comment: @KevinPaxman I've extended my answer to your question; hopefully the update will help.

Comment: In the end, I ended up making a taxonomy for the field, with a tickbox for "sort me to the top" - which only occurred to me because you mentioned weights. Thanks!